# How deuces play in this?

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, odds, hand

I'm new to poker, I saw this [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/PokerStars/status/1396883348631572480) and people reporting 16 outs and including three deuces and I cannot understand how deuces play in this? Question on the tweet is how many outs does AA hero have?

[image]

- 9 clubs (for flush)
- 2 aces
- 2 jacks (jack of clubs already accounted for)
- 3 deuces ???

Why deuces? Does AA22 become higher two-pair? But then it also becomes higher by following same logic with AA33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, TT and so on? And doesn't KT give A high straight for hero?

I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image doesn't reflect the correct state of the hand. The question is actually referring to the outs after the turn.

Hero: A♣ A♠

Villain: Q⋄ 9⋄

Board: 9♣ J♥ Q♣

Turn: 2♣

Here there are the 16 outs you indicated.

Yes, AA22 is a higher two pair than QQ99, as two pairs are ranked by the higher pair first, then the second pair, and finally kicker.

Comment: You are right, I rewatched the video, the deuce on Turn is visible for like split second and video resets for me. I never noticed the Turn card. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's referring to the outs you get for a repeated card, so they put "deuces" as an example. It's the only possible explanation I can find.